# How to access getbbox on a svg element in a cypress test

Tags: svg, cypress

I have a SVG which includes text elements. I can get the text of the elements in my cypress test, but when I try to call getbbox() I get the error 'TypeError: text.getBBox is not a function'. If I understand correctly cypress is returning text as a htmlELement, and I need an SVGElement to call getbbox() on, but whats best practice to do that in the context of a cypress test?

```
cy.get('svg#osmdSvgPage1').get("text").each(textElement => {
    var text = textElement.text(); //successful
    //do some stuff
    var bbox = textElement.getbbox(); //throws 'TypeError: text.getBBox is not a function'
    //do more stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRT to [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox), it must be called on the native SVGGraphicsElement, but you have called it on the `jQuery` object passed into `.each()`.

Just add an index like this to unwrap the jQuery object:

```js
var bbox = textElement[0].getBBox()
```

---

WRT `cy.get('svg#osmdSvgPage1').get("text")` I think you want this instead

```js
cy.get('svg#osmdSvgPage1').find("text")
```

assuming the text elements are within the `svg`.

If there's only one `svg`, you can just use

```js
cy.get("text")
```

but if there are several `svg` on the page `cy.get('svg#osmdSvgPage1').get("text")` will return all the `text` from all `svg`, because `.get("text")` scans the whole page by default.